# Date picker date not saving to database

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, datepicker

I am using a date picker on a form and it selects the date in the format "20 May 2014"

in the form processing i have tried to amend this to save in the correct (Y m d) format but every time i save it it still stores as 0000-00-00 in the database. Not sure what is going on as this WAS working before?

form processing code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Process the form
$project_title = mysql_prep($_POST["project_title"]);
$start_date = $_POST["start_date"];
$stage = $_POST["stage"];
$acc_manager = $_POST["acc_manager"];
$designer = $_POST["designer"];
$url = $_POST["url"];

$timestamp = strtotime($start_date);
$start_date2 = date("Y m d", $timestamp);

$query  = "INSERT INTO projects (";
$query .= " project_title, start_date, stage, acc_manager, designer, url";
$query .= " ) VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$project_title}', '{$start_date2}', '{$stage}', '{$acc_manager}', '{$designer}', '{$url}' ";
$query .= ")";

echo $query;

try { $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return 'Caught exception: '+  $e->getMessage()+ "\n";
}
//Test if there was a query error
if ($result) {
    //Success
    // would normally use a redirect ie redirect_to("somepage.php");
    //$message = "Subject created.";
    redirect_to("projects.php");
}else {
    //failure
    //$message = "Subject creation failed.";
    //redirect_to("add_project.php");
    echo $query;
}
} else {
// This is probably a GET request
redirect_to("add_project.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct $start_date2 date string.

Try:

```
date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```